# Carnot cycle and entropy

Tags: thermodynamics

From what I understand, in the Carnot cycle summing qi/Ti for each step results in zero, thus indicating a new state function, entropy = qrev/T. But since dE = 0 = q+w, then q = -w, and looking at the equations derived from the cycle summing wi/Ti for each step should also result in zero. So why can't one also define entropy as wrev/T?

Answer (score 0):

Why did you say that $dE=0$? In a Carnot cycle you have an adiabatic transformation, where $dQ=0$ and $dE=-dW$.

Comment: I was referring to the complete cycle, dE = 0.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not understand the question. However, the fact that in a cycle $\Delta Q/T=W/T=0$ does not mean that integrating over a transformation those quantities, you have the same value (for example, along an isochoric process you have that $\int d W/T=0$, while $\Delta S= n C_{v} \log (T_{f}/T_{i})$). Of course, you can define another state function starting from $W/T$, but you can't say that it coincides with the entropy.